# Pyinstaller --hidden-imports not wirking

Tags: python, pyinstaller, hidden

I'm trying to build an exe file from a python game using PyBox2D and Pyglet.

When I build the exe there occurs an error that a module cannot be imported:
`Unable to import the back-end pyglet: module 'gui.backends' has no attribute 'pyglet_framework'`
I guess this happens because this file only gets imported indirectly/hidden from another file with `__import__()`

This is my project hierarchy:
[image]

I've tried to add the file to pyinstaller on multiple ways. From the directory `/SpaceJam/building` I've tried calling:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile "../game/spacejam.py" --hidden-import="gui/framework/backends/pyglet_framework.py"
pyinstaller.exe --onefile "../game/spacejam.py" --hidden-import="../gui/framework/backends/pyglet_framework.py"
pyinstaller.exe --onefile "../game/spacejam.py" --hidden-import="../gui/framework/backends/pyglet_framework"
pyinstaller.exe --onefile "../game/spacejam.py" --hidden-import="../gui/framework/backends/*"
```

but none of that seemed to change anything in the error message.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Does somebody have an idea what I might be doing wrong or why the --hidden-import argument doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That argument [expects a *module name*](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-hidden-import), not a filesystem path. How would you `import` it?

I'm not totally clear on how your project is set up, but try

```
--hidden-import gui.backends.pyglet_framework
```